# Hiding all files in a user chosen directory

Tags: applescript

So basically I want to be able to take all of the files in a folder and hide them but it always stops at this point with Applescript error -1700

```
tell application "Finder" 
        set filePath to entire contents of (choose folder with 
        prompt "Please choose your folder") as alias list
        set pFilePath to POSIX path of filePath
end tell
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: The variable `filePath` is a _list_ of items, you need to get POSIX paths of _each_ item.  Hidden items can easily be seen in the Finder or Terminal, though - what are you really trying to do?

Comment: well what I want it to do is basically be able to zip all of the contents of a folder with a password. just thought this would an easier way to ask about doing the same sort of thing

Comment: You can use the `zip` shell utility, but another way is to use `Disk Utility` to create a new image from a folder and choose an encryption.

Comment: I had no idea of this even existing thank you